# Unable to upload image in codigniter, getting an wrong path error

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, file-upload, frameworks

I'm working on a project where I was trying to upload image by using jquery ajax + codeigniter.

Don't know why I'm getting following issue:

> **Error:
> The upload path does not appear to be valid.**

Is there anything i missed in following code?

> **upload_product_image()** is the method that handle the upload task

```
public function upload_product_image()
  {
    if(isset($_FILES["file"]["name"]))
     {
      $config['upload_path'] = 'upload/';
      $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg';
      $config['max_width'] = 0;
      $config['max_height'] = 0;
      $config['max_size'] = 0;
      $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

      $this->load->library('upload', $config);

      if(!$this->upload->do_upload('file'))
      {
         echo 'Error: '. $this->upload->display_errors();
         echo '<hr>';
         echo $config['upload_path'];
      }
      else
      {
        $arr_image = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        print_r($arr_image);
      }
     }
  }
```

> Following code is the **HTML Code**

```
<div class="card mb-2">
    <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseone">
    <div class="card-header">
         Upload Product Image(One) <span class="float-right text-danger">Size(192X138)</span>
    </div>
    </a>
    <div id="collapseone" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group row" >
          <div class="col-sm-3 text-center" style="position:relative;">
            <img id="product_img_one_img_preview" src="upload/default/coming_soon.svg" class="w-100 img-fluid img-thumbnail" />
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary mt-2" onclick="$('#product_img_one_box').trigger('click'); return false;"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload file</a>
              <div id="product_img_one_loader"></div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-sm-9 my-auto">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" value="upload/default/coming_soon.svg" name="product_img_one" id="product_img_one" class="form-control" />
               <input type="file" name="" class="form-control-file border hidden" id="product_img_one_box">
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
```

> And following is the **jQuery code** that I used

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#product_img_one_loader").hide();
       $('#product_img_one_box').on('change', function(){
            var fd = new FormData();
            var files = $(this)[0].files[0];
            fd.append('file', files);
            console.log(fd);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://mywebsite.com/shop/admin/upload_product_image',
                type: "post",
                data: fd,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $("#product_img_one_loader").html('<div class="lds-facebook" style="position:absolute;top: 35%;left: 40%;"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>');
                    $("#product_img_one_loader").show();

                },
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#product_img_one_loader").html('');
                    // $("#product_img_one_loader").hide();

                    $("#product_img_one_loader").html(response);

                    // alert(response);
                    // if (response != 0) {
                    //
                    // } else {
                    //   alert('file not uploaded');
                    // }
                },
                complete: function(data) {
                  // $("#product_img_one_loader").html('');
                  // $("#product_img_one_loader").hide();
                }
            });

          });
     });
```

Comment: Make sure that the directory is writeable. What chmod is set on it?

Comment: It is auto set by 0755

Answer (score 1):

The upload path must be defined as an absolute server path, not a relative one.

Instead of `$config['upload_path'] = 'upload/';` try `$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'upload/';`

That small change will force the upload to go in the `upload` directory which is located in the same directory as the front controller (CI's main `index.php` file).

Your current code is looking for an `upload` directory located in the same place as your controller (`application/controllers/upload/`), which is not what you want.

Also, check the directory and its contents are owned and writable by the PHP process (755 is a good place to start)... a simple `-ls -l` will give you all information you need on this matter

Comment: I would expand on this answer to also make sure that your folder has the correct chmod and ownership. If those 3 things are correct you shouldn't have a problem.